# smooth transitioning between layers in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

is there a way to switch baselayers in a smooth manner. For example I have this simple map (taken from [here](https://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/))
with two baselayers. When you change selection then there is something like flickering to move from one baselayer to the other.

Do you know if this can be done in a nice smooth way?

There is a similar post which is 9yrs old but didnt have a solution. I hope you dont mind me posting this one now. Maybe there is something new after 9years.

PS. For some strange reason the snippet doesnt seem to work here. It looks fine on my local system...

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>A Leaflet map!</title>

    <!-- leaflet v 1.0.3 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css"/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>

    <style>
        #map {
            height: 100%
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map"></div>

<script>


    var osm = L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 19,
        attribution: '© OpenStreetMap'
    });

    var osmHOT = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 19,
        attribution: '© OpenStreetMap contributors, Tiles style by Humanitarian OpenStreetMap Team hosted by OpenStreetMap France'
    });

    var map = L.map('map', {
        center: [39.73, -104.99],
        zoom: 10,
        layers: [osm]
    });

    var baseMaps = {
        "OpenStreetMap": osm,
        "OpenStreetMap.HOT": osmHOT
    };

    var layerControl = L.control.layers(baseMaps, {}).addTo(map);


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.GridLayer.FadeOut

Comment: Thanks! Didnt know that, thanks so much Ivan. If you wish write that as an answer (instead of a comment) and I will accept it